# Java Dice Roller Loops

Tags: java

So I am having an issue figuring out how to create a loop and bring another class over in a dice game application I have to create for a school project. The game has to keep user score for each round 18 is the max score and if a user Rolls over 10 in 1 round his points are lost and he starts the next round at 1 point. The game also has to validate when the user enters Y to Roll or R to stop. Some help on this would be greatly appreciated. Im having problems with setting up a loop in which to continue the game after Y is entered or Tell the user the game has stopped after R is entered. So after Y is entered the loop would Print out "Round1" Roll:6 [Y or R], user entered Y, Print out "Round 2" and so on and i dont know how to validate user input.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;
import java.lang.Boolean;

public class Player {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        String player;
        String playerAnswer;
        Boolean answer = true;
        int RoundScore;
        int TotalScore;
        int playerScore;
        int Round;
        Scanner user = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter your First Name to play!");
        player = user.nextLine();
        playerAnswer = user.nextLine();
        {
            System.out.println("Your Name:" + "" + player);
            System.out.println("Welcome" + "" + player + "" + "To Dice Game");
            System.out.println("Enter Y to Roll or R to STop:[Y or R]" + "" + playerAnswer.toUpperCase());
        }
    }
}



package Project4;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Dice{
    public static void main(String[] args){

        Random dice = new Random();
        int number = 0;
        for(int counter = 1; counter <= 1; counter++)
            number = 1 + dice.nextInt(18);
        System.out.println(number + "");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something for you to note I don't think there's a (1) die can roll up to 18. The range for 3 dice should be 3 - 18 instead of 1 - 18.

```
number = 3 + dice.nextInt(16);
```

For the loop issue use do while loop, and assign a variable to get the and noticed how your playerAnswer should be under the System.out.println.

```
int rounds = 1;

do {

// codes that you want to loop
System.out.println("Welcome" + "" + player + "" + "To Dice Game");
System.out.println("Round " + rounds); // this will annouce the number of rounds
System.out.println("Enter Y to Roll or R to STop:[Y or R]")
playerAnswer = user.nextLine();
rounds++;

} while (playerAnswer.equalsIgnoreCase("y");
```

Also, I don't think you can have 2 main method here as you're creating "an" application, not 2 different application. I would suggest that you create a sub method using

```
public static void rollDice()
{
    // codes for rolling the dice

}
```

and to call the rollDice method just do a

rollDice();

However, the application you're creating seems to be small and doing just the dice roll, if I am you I wouldn't even need to create a method for it.

You are probably trying to learn how to create a class. Seeing your codes, you seems like you aren't that great in Java yet. I would suggest that you re-start learning Java from the basics. I think you need to pay more attention in your school class.

Comment: While `3 + dice.nextInt(16);` generates the proper range for 3 dice, the distribution is very different. No idea if there's a 18-sided die, but it could be as 12 and 20 sided dice are common.

Comment: You can have any number of `main` methods (though only one per class) and it even makes sense (use `java Demo` or `java Main` or whatever).

Comment: I don't think he's creating 2 separate application for that purpose. The nearest I trying to figure out what he's doing is he's trying to create another Dice object through a class to call in the Dice roll method. However since the application is small, I personally would suggest he create a void method in the main app itself.

Comment: Agreed that the OP hardly knows what he's doing (and needs any advice he get get), but you wrote a sentence which isn't true. What about "you can't have 2 main methods and expect them to do anything useful in your case"?

Comment: Oh right, I just reviewed what I wrote about having the 2 main methods. Thanks for correcting me.